# Find minium value that is maximum times in Array Perl

Tags: perl

I have a requirement to find out the minimum value that is occurring maximum times in the array .I have store those values in other array .

```
my @arr=(1,2,3,4,1,3,4,1);
```

1 is the minimum value that is occurring maximum times.

Comment: How about `my @arr=(1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1);`? 1 is smaller while 2 occurs more times?

Comment: so 2 will be the output as i think

Comment: yes @GauravPandey your right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this it will work perfect for you

```
my @arr=(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1);
my %count;
foreach (@arr){
    $count{$_}++;
}
my ($min_by_value) = sort { $a <=> $b} keys %count;
my ($max_by_count) = sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count;
my $max =
    ($count{$min_by_value} >= $count{$max_by_count}) ? $min_by_value : $max_by_count;
print "minimum value max times = $max\n";
```

Comment: this is not working as if the all the values are same then it is working

Comment: @Rahul i have updated my answer i have checked this it's working fine

Answer (score 3):

If there are two or more elements occurring same number of times, smaller is preferred:

```
my @arr=(1,2,3,4,1,3,4,1);

my %seen;
$seen{$_}++ for @arr;

my ($min_val) = sort { $seen{$b} <=> $seen{$a} || $a <=> $b } keys %seen;
print "$min_val\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hash to count the occurrences of each number. The most frequent numbers can be found as having the frequence equal to the `max` of the frequences, the minimum among them can be found by `min`, both `min` and `max` come from `List::Util`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw(min max);

my @arr = (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1);
my %occurrences;
$occurrences{$_}++ for @arr;
my $max_freq = max(values %occurrences);
print min(grep $max_freq == $occurrences{$_}, keys %occurrences);
```